# Nextjs 13 appdir not-found page not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization

In the nextjs 13 appdir with i18n, the custom not-found page does not work and shows default 404 page, which is inside the [lng] folder on the same level as the layout, has anyone encountered such and issue and how to solve it?
From here I took the ref https://locize.com/blog/next-13-app-dir-i18n/

tried to create not-found.jsx file in [lng] folder, but it still shows default 404 page

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737684/nextjs-13-how-to-create-a-multilingual-not-found-page-using-route-groups) answer your question?